# Почему репозиторий не должен возвращать DTO?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Везде пишут, что репозиторий не должен возвращать DTO... Как быть тогда? возвращать объект или массив? Но в него можно добавить что угодно, где угодно. Если у меня изменятся получаемые данные, то репозиторий отдаст сразу вместе с ними, и я даже не замечу этого. DTO же по факту гарантирует, что я получу объект в едином виде, и в дальнейшем вижу что принимаю, и что отдаю.

Использую репозиторий чисто для CRUD действий, чтобы иметь прослойку для eloquent моделей, если вдруг решу их заменить.

Подскажите, что в моем случае лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DTO - это Data Transfer Object. Т.е. объект, которые используется передачи данных клиенту или наоборот получения данных от него.

Формат передачи этих данных вполне может не соответствовать структуре БД, а чаще всего он и не должен ей соответствовать. Если передавать данные в чистом виде, как они представлены в таблицах/моделях БД, то это далеко не всегда удобно для работы клиента в следствие сложной структуры, наличия лишних (которые данный клиент в рамках данной задачи не обрабатывает) данных, неподходящего представления данных (например нужно сконвертировать формат даты, времени и т.д.).

Кроме того, использование DTO в качестве модели для репозитория приводит к сильной связности в коде вследствие нарушения принципа MVC и как закономерный результат поддержка и развитие такого кода заметно усложняется, а иногда и становится просто невозможной. Например, если у вашего сервиса 2 клиента, каждый из которых требует примерно одни и те же данные, но в разных представлениях и/или с небольшими отличиями. Вы же не будете заводить для каждого из них свою структуру таблиц с одинаковыми данными?..

Да и если ваш протокол единый для всех клиентов. Со временем может возникнуть задача что-то поменять. Что проще поменять, структуру таблиц или простенький алгоритм преобразования модели в DTO?

Поэтому лучше разделить между собой DTO и модели. И репозиторий действительно не должен работать с DTO. Скажу больше. Логика работы с DTO в идеале не должна выходить за пределы "транспортного" слоя (в MVC это контроллеры).

Comment: а что мне отдавать в репозитории тогда? я же не могу отдавать просто массивы?

Comment: я думал репозиторий отдаст дто, контроллер получит дто, на дто повешу ресурс, который приведет в нужный вид данные для пользователя

Comment: Если Вы получаете запросом из репозитория несколько объектов одной модели у Вас по-любому будет массив. Репозиторий должен отдавать объекты моделей (одиночные или массивом), а в DTO их можно преобразовать уже в методах контроллеров.

Comment: но я не могу отдавать модели... если я захочу потом doctrine воткнуть, все репозитории умрут, тк отдают инстанс eloquent model

Comment: @PaulWall, а вы не должны отдавать модели. Вы должны отдавать DTO. Соответственно можно создать сервис, который на входе принимает модель, а на выходе DTO и наоборот. Сервисов можно создать несколько, для eloquent, для doctrine

Comment: @ArchDemon можете подсказать плиз, хотя бы ссылкой какой нибудь, как сделать такие сервисы. Сейчас кроме как воткнуть new UserDTO($array) на выходные данные репозитория ничего не приходит в голову

Comment: @PaulWall, с точки зрения принципа единой ответственности не очень хорошо, чтобы DTO знал как себя создать из входных данных. Должен быть некий посредник, который на вход принимает входные данные, а на выходе выдаёт DTO. Я его назвал сервис, но это лишь абстракция. Им может выступать несколько шаблонов. Всё зависит от ваших потребностей. Если ваш вариант вас устраивает, то ничего страшного. Когда не будет, зададите ещё один вопрос. Мы вас обязательно подскажем